# how to desin ui using clipper in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to clipper on top and botton of a screen like gien image ?[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtRPf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9b1o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffis0.png)

how add blue cliper on top of screen and second cliper on buttom of screen using flutter and dart